# Errores al instalar php por defecto en centos 7.0.1416

Tags: php, centos7

El comando para la instalación es el siguiente.

```
yum install php*
```

error 1. conflicto con php-mysqlnd-5.4.16

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error 2. Se detiene cuando la instalación comienza

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La solución aparece en la misma consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Para poder saltar el problema use el siguiente comando para la instalación

   yum install php* --skip-broken
2. Para el segundo caso basto agregar estos dos comandos para que la instalacion prosiguiera (hacer lo mismo cada vez que se aparezca el mensaje)

```
#rm /dev/urandom
#mknod -m 644 /dev/urandom c 1 9
```